# Toggleclass resalta la clase pero no la agrega

Tags: html, jquery

Resulta que quiero mostrar y ocultar información al dar click, pero al dar click solo resalta la clase pero no agrega nada

```
<div class="tabs tabs-producto">
   <div class="tab-one">
      <span>Acerca del producto</span>
   </div>
</div>

<section class="product-specs"></section>
```

```
.product-specs{
  display:none;
}

.opened{
  display:block;
}
```

```
$(".tabs-producto .tab-one").click(function() {
     $(".product-specs").toggleClass("opened");
});
```

¿que estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias

Comment: Hice pruebas con tu codigo y funciona correctamente, agrega la clase y la quita al dar clic, pero no muestra nada por que tu section no tiene nada dentro de el.

Comment: bien raro porque a mi no me funciona :(.
me resalta la clase por un momento y ya, no agrega la clase

Comment: Trata de poner important en los displays. Puede que otros displays solapen a los tuyos.

Comment: Revisa el ejemplo en este fiddle, y comparalo, solamente agregue un div dentro del section para que veas a lo que me refiero con el comportamiento: https://jsfiddle.net/RicardoP/7tmju3ar/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible que te falte indicar que se vincule el evento `click()` cuando haya terminado de cargar el **DOM** para evitar el tratar de acceder a un elemento que no se encuentra aun disponible. Con **JQuery** podemos hacerlo a través de la siguiente función:

**JQuery**

```
$(function () {
  //Aquí dentro tu código
});
```

Te adjunto un ejemplo realizado basándome en tu código y totalmente funcional.

```js
$(function () {
  $(".tabs-producto .tab-one").click(function() {
     $(".product-specs").toggleClass("opened");
  });
});
```

```css
.tabs-producto {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.product-specs{
  display:none;
}

.opened {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tabs tabs-producto">
   <div class="tab-one">
      <span>Acerca del producto</span>
   </div>
</div>

<section class="product-specs"><p>Texto oculto</p></section>
```

Answer (score -1):

Pues por lo que veo tienes que hacerle toogleClass es a .product-specs para poder mostrar el elemento